# Is it possible to integrate sms process in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-translation

I have searched sms code for magento 2. But there is only purchased extension only there. Is it possible to integrate sms in magento 2 by only coding?

Comment: On which event you want to send sms?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you may be want to fire SMS on order status `pending, processing, complete.

So, in that case, you can use [`Events and observers`](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html)

> Events are dispatched by modules when certain actions are triggered.
>   In addition to its own events, Magento allows you to create your own
>   events that can be dispatched in your code. When an event is
>   dispatched, it can pass data to any observers configured to watch that
>   event.

Events and observers provide a point where you can run some code.

For you can use `sales_order_save_commit_after` event, at **this event fire run an observer which will track order status Change.**

On event this  event, you can get old Data: using `$Object->getOrigData();`

and you can get new Data using `$object->getData()`,SO here you can get order status changs easily and fire  the sms

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        if (!$order->getId()) {

            return $this;
        }



        $OldData=$order->getOrigData();
        $NewData=$order->getData();
        $OldState==$order->getOrigData('state');
        $NewState=$order->getState();
        $OldStatus=$order->getOrigData('status');
        $NewStatus=$order->getStatus();


        /* Fire sms when New Status  and  old Statu are not same */
        if($OldStatus!=$NewStatus){
            //fire sms;
      // Write your  sms code at here               
        }
  }
}
```